# How to populate a new variable based on a condition of two other variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I would like to create a variable that takes a certain value in a certain year, by country.

```
Country Year Price Price_2018
   A    2016  1      4
   A    2017  3      4
   A    2018  4      4
   B    2016  1      5
   B    2017  7      5
   B    2018  5      5
   C    2016  1      3
   C    2017  6      3
   C    2018  3      3
```

As above, I'd like to create the variable Price_2018 that, for each country, take the price in 2018 and populates each observation with this value. Would anyone be able to help here? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a variable for each year, so you can try this approach reshaping data and then merging using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% left_join(df %>%
  mutate(Year=paste0('Price_',Year)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year,values_from=Price))
```

Output:

```
  Country Year Price Price_2016 Price_2017 Price_2018
1       A 2016     1          1          3          4
2       A 2017     3          1          3          4
3       A 2018     4          1          3          4
4       B 2016     1          1          7          5
5       B 2017     7          1          7          5
6       B 2018     5          1          7          5
7       C 2016     1          1          6          3
8       C 2017     6          1          6          3
9       C 2018     3          1          6          3
```

And if you only want `2018`:

```
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>% left_join(df %>% filter(Year==2018) %>%
  mutate(Year=paste0('Price_',Year)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year,values_from=Price))
```

Output:

```
  Country Year Price Price_2018
1       A 2016     1          4
2       A 2017     3          4
3       A 2018     4          4
4       B 2016     1          5
5       B 2017     7          5
6       B 2018     5          5
7       C 2016     1          3
8       C 2017     6          3
9       C 2018     3          3
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C"), Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2018L), Price = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can either use `==` (assuming there are only unique 'Year' for each 'Country')

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    mutate(Price_2018 = Price[Year == 2018])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Country [3]
#  Country  Year Price Price_2018
#  <chr>   <int> <int>      <int>
#1 A        2016     1          4
#2 A        2017     3          4
#3 A        2018     4          4
#4 B        2016     1          5
#5 B        2017     7          5
#6 B        2018     5          5
#7 C        2016     1          3
#8 C        2017     6          3
#9 C        2018     3          3
```

---

Or `match`

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(Country) %>%
     mutate(Price_2018 = Price[match(2018, Year)])
```

---

If we need to create multiple 'Year' column, an easier option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(unique(df1$Year), ~ df1 %>%  group_by(Country) %>%
    transmute(!! str_c('Price_', .x) :=  Price[Year == .x]) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-Country)) %>%
    mutate(df1, .)
#  Country Year Price Price_2016 Price_2017 Price_2018
#1       A 2016     1          1          3          4
#2       A 2017     3          1          3          4
#3       A 2018     4          1          3          4
#4       B 2016     1          1          7          5
#5       B 2017     7          1          7          5
#6       B 2018     5          1          7          5
#7       C 2016     1          1          6          3
#8       C 2017     6          1          6          3
#9       C 2018     3          1          6          3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C"), Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2018L), Price = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```